# Update a column in snowflake table based on another snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two snowflake tables. Table 'TEST' has 3 columns where 'HASH_KEY' columns is getting updated as concat of columns 'name' and 'id' as in the below code.

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST (
  id varchar(100), 
  name varchar(100),
  HASH_KEY VARCHAR(64)
);    

INSERT INTO TEST values (100, 'ABC', null);
INSERT INTO TEST values (200, 'XYZ', null);


update TEST set HASH_KEY = CONCAT_WS('|',id,name);
```

Above code works completely fine
My requirement is instead of hardcoding id and name column in update statement. I want to implement the same using 'KEY_COLUMNS' column from control table

My control table looks like below

```
create OR REPLACE table CONTROL_TABLE (
  KEY_COLUMNS VARCHAR,
  COL1 VARCHAR,
  COL2 VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO CONTROL_TABLE values ('id,name', null, null);
```

The KEY_COLUMNS column has the value id,name, so my update statement should pick those columns from test table and concat the values of those columns something like below

```
update TEST set HASH_KEY = CONCAT_WS('|', (select KEY_COLUMNS from CONTROL_TABLE));
```

I am getting below value for HASH_KEY column

```
id,name
id,name
```

Expected value of HASH_KEY column

```
100|ABC
200|XYZ
```

Comment: you are getting `id,name` because that is the value of `KEY_COLUMNS` that you have inserted in CONTROL_TABLES. What you want requires something more dynamic,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you did lets setup some data:

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST (
  id varchar(100), 
  name varchar(100),
  HASH_KEY VARCHAR(64)
);    

INSERT INTO TEST values
    (100, 'ABC', null),
    (200, 'XYZ', null);
```

I have changed `CONTROL_TABLE` to have the name of the name of the source table

```
create OR REPLACE table CONTROL_TABLE (
  KEY_COLUMNS VARCHAR,
  table_name VARCHAR,
  COL2 VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO CONTROL_TABLE values ('id,name', 'TEST', null);
```

Now we can use [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/) to dynamically build our SQL:

```
DECLARE
   source_tbl STRING := 'TEST';
   hash_columns STRING;
   query STRING;
BEGIN

  SELECT KEY_COLUMNS INTO :hash_columns FROM CONTROL_TABLE WHERE table_name = :source_tbl;
  
  QUERY := 'update '|| source_tbl ||' set HASH_KEY = CONCAT_WS(\'|\','|| :hash_columns ||');';
                 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   
   RETURN :QUERY;
END;
```

and return is the update that was run:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| update TEST set HASH_KEY = CONCAT_WS('|',id,name); |

[image]

For [classic console](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html#passing-a-block-as-a-string-literal-to-execute-immediate) wrap in an `execute immediate $$<block>$$`

```
execute immediate $$
DECLARE
   source_tbl STRING := 'TEST';
   hash_columns STRING;
   query STRING;
BEGIN

  SELECT KEY_COLUMNS INTO :hash_columns FROM CONTROL_TABLE WHERE table_name = :source_tbl;
  
  QUERY := 'update '|| source_tbl ||' set HASH_KEY = CONCAT_WS(\'|\','|| :hash_columns ||');';
                 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   
   RETURN :QUERY;
END;
$$;
```

and if we check the data:

```
SELECT * from test;
```

was see the results we where expecting:

| ID | NAME | HASH_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ABC | 100|ABC |
| 200 | XYZ | 200|XYZ |

Comment: I am getting "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 31 unexpected '<EOF>'." error

Comment: Ah, you are running the classic console, will add the classic syntax also. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html